# Git Workflow Questions

Tags: git, magento, branch

So, I know this has been asked to death, but in all of my countless hours of searching I've yet to figure this out completely.

So here's the workflow I have:

- Production (live) environment is only updated with patches as needed.
- Dev environment (on same server as production, different docroot) are the files currently being worked on
- My local repo which is currently cloned from the Dev environment, but I would like to manage production in another cloned repo using Phpstorm

Production and Dev are two completely different deployments, they cannot be merged at the moment as too much is different and it would render production unusable. We are doing some major overhaul in Magento and trying to isolate Dev and Production into their own branches, so neither will have anything to do with each other until the next version release.

I'm having major issues with Github integration. When I run git push origin dev or git push origin production, when I go to github to check the changes I am seeing message changes in all 3 branches, and I don't want this happening at all, even if it is metadata on the folders, and not the files themselves being changed. One should have nothing to do with the other until merged.

This is getting very frustrating as I don't want either branch to even TOUCH master, until I'm ready to merge anything. I want to be able to pull dev branch to the Dev environment, production branch to Production environment, and have both branches as separate repos on my local system that I can edit each individually. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I found the reason why branches were getting mixed up was because I was not using checkout before committing, if its a new local working tree, the remote must first be pulled, then I unzipped a tarball of the modifications to dev on top of the master branch pull, checked out dev, then committed and pushed without issues.

Here's a great pdf of github workflow for those interested. 
http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf

Also thanks to bish for his helpful article as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you pushed explicitly with `git push origin production`, your change will only be shown on the production branch. Unless your current branch is not **production**, which in this case i'm not completely sure on what would happens.

The network page on github (ex: https://github.com/magento/magento2/network) is a good place to look on how your branches are diverging in more a visual manner, another way to see this same is with the **gitk** tool on your machine.

About your local environment, you just need to clone the repository once and cycle through the branches with `git checkout <branch_name>`

Comment: Yea, I must be having a bug with github then because it is updating descriptions of folders and files on all 3 branches even with no actual file changes. Also doesn't git checkout also pull files? I wanted to switch without pulling the branch over production.

Answer (score 1):

> > and have both branches as separate repos

they are in ONE repo, but on DIFFERENT branches, so check out the specific branch in PHPSTORM you are working on. If your are finisht you only push this branch. So if you work on dev. If you are working now on dev and in 5 minutes on live, then just change branches - that is exaclty what they are for.

In your PHPStorm you have on the right buttom a field "git: ", just click there and a submenu opens with the point "local branches". In this you can switch between your local branches.

This article explains more about git workflow in detail:
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my main issue is not necessarily with Phpstorm, sorry if my question was unclear, but the main issue is that the repos on the actual live server arent staying separate from each other on github. Dev had deviated so far from production, I wanted to give it it's own branch without affecting master or either branch for that matter, so i couldnt use checkout without syncing a snapshot.

Comment: May I ask if you have branches or do you only work on the same one and only master-branch

Comment: Both dev and production were tied to master at one point, we got this deployment post production, so we cloned production to dev, and are reworking it to flow with the new m2epro. We only put code into production that has proven stable in testing. We have come to start finding that production needs its own branch, my problem was being unable to properly detach from the master and use a new branch for production. I also set a branch for dev. But when I push from either of the two, I see files getting uploaded to all 3 branches, even when i explicitly say "git push origin dev" or prod branch.

Comment: I have also removed the .git folder from each and starting the repo over, the problem is it needs first commit to declare a master I believe.. from what I've read. I'm relatively new to git but I understand the flow somewhat. I feel like this shouldnt have to happen.

Comment: If the work with branches are not so clear to you thins link might help you. I got several problems understanding the switch from our SVN-workflow to our git-workflow when we were switching, and this article helped me a lot: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Wow, that was a very thorough article. Thanks! I'll add this to your answer and mark it as the answer.